# Need to create excel sheet in users desktop

Tags: c#

In my project i need to create an excel file in users desktop. Code written in my visual studio is.

```
    string sPathTestData1 = "\\AdaptiveModulations.xls";
                    string sPathTestData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\AdaptiveModulations" + sPathTestData1;
                    string sheet = "Sheet1";
                    string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\AdaptiveModulations";
  if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                    ExcelUtils.createExcelFile(sPathTestData,sheet);
                }
                else
                {
                    ExcelUtils.setExcelFile(sPathTestData,sheet);


                }
```

This code is working perfectly in my system and creating folder with excel file but when i copied the exe from C:\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\AMCalculator\AMCalculator\bin\Debug folder and saved in another machine it showing error can anyone help on this

Comment: "it showing error" aaaaaaand what error might that be? And which line is the error occurring on?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: when i run the application in visual studio i didn't get any errors and application working fine, creating folder and excel file also. but if i run the .exe file in other system or outside visual studio, application is creating folder only not excel file and application stops working this is my error.

Comment: It might be an unhandled exception thrown only under certain circumstances somewhere in your code. Consider wrapping vulnerable code regions (file I/O operations, access to external resources etc.) inside `try/catch` blocks to handle and display/log errors.

Comment: code working fine in Visual studio without any errors and when  i run my application outside visual studio  using .exe it creating directory  but excel sheet is not creating and application stops working.

Answer (score 0):

I have added try/catch blocks in my classes 
In ExcelUtils Class :

```
public static void createExcelFile(String filepath, String sheetName)
        {
            try
            {
                using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                {
                       workBook = new HSSFWorkbook();
                       workSheet = workBook.CreateSheet(sheetName);
                       workBook.Write(stream);
                       stream.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to Create File. Exception is : " + e);
            }
        }

        public static void setExcelFile(string filepath, string sheetName)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File Path is : " + filepath);
                workBook = WorkbookFactory.Create(new FileStream(
                               Path.GetFullPath(filepath),
                               FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read,
                               FileShare.ReadWrite));

                workSheet = workBook.GetSheet(sheetName);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to Load File. Exception is : " + e);
            }
        }
```

In My main class :

```
            if (!File.Exists(sPathTestData))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            try
            {
                ExcelUtils.createExcelFile(sPathTestData, sheet);
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException fe)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to Create File. Exception is : " + fe);
            }
           }
            else
            {
            try
            {
                ExcelUtils.setExcelFile(sPathTestData, sheet);
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException fe)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to Load File. Exception is : " + fe);
            }
            }
```